# How to arrange the Numpy array output in separate rows to one .csv file and to put the name of the processed image in the first cell of a row?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, output

I have code with two image processing funcions which print the result to the console:

```
  def haralick(self):     #function for Haralick features computation
   for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
     imgg = mahotas.imread (filename)
     cancertwo = mahotas.features.haralick (imgg)
     arr = numpy.array([cancertwo])
       for x in arr:
         for y in arr:
          for h in y:
            for z in h: print '%f' %z
   def humoments(self):               #function for HuMoments computation
     for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
      img = cv.LoadImageM(filename, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
      cancer = cv.GetHuMoments(cv.Moments(img))
      arr = numpy.array([cancer])
        for x in arr:
         for x in cancer:
           print '%f' %x
```

I need to put the numeric result of computations into one .csv file 'ResultsComp'

How to change the line numpy.savetxt("ResultsComp.csv", array.flat[:50], delimiter=" ") to arrange the numeric

output in separate rows in one .csv file and to put the name of the processed image in the first cell of a row?

Thank you.